# Why query without and with EXPLAIN shows different number of rows?

Tags: mysql, sql-execution-plan

I have the following query below:
1- SELECT count(*) FROM students
2- EXPLAIN SELECT count(*) FROM students

[image]

Comment: Could you have a caching issue going on?  Have you tried exiting Workbench and going back in again?

Comment: Most DB engines actually keep a record of how many rows there are, but InnoDB does not and so must actually perform this count. Have you tried specifying which column is counted. Does the estimate change based on whether its using an indexed column or not. If you make a copy of the table into a MyISAM engine, is there a difference then?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html):

> The rows column indicates the number of rows MySQL believes it must examine to execute the query.
>
> For InnoDB tables, this number is an estimate, and may not always be exact.

I don't know how it decides how to "estimate".

**Update:**

This answer on [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49275/mysql-looking-up-more-rows-than-needed-indexing-issue) suggests it's based on index statistics:

> The optimizer gathers information about different possible query plans, and chooses the one with the lowest cost. The information shown in EXPLAIN is the information the optimizer gathered about the plan it selected.

This still doesn't *quite* explain what's happened in the background.